# How to set items from cell to end of column in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to change my y-min and y-max values on my chart as well as make sure all of the tick labels are forced to be shown. Any suggestions on how to do that with this code in mind?

The problems I'm having is the conventional method of using "Range("R2:R" & LastRow).Select" isn't working because im using the "set" operator.

```
Sub MakeFinanceChart()

    Dim rX1 As Range rY1 As Range, rX2 As Range, rY2 As Range, _
        rX3 As Range, rY3 As Range, rX4 As Range, rY4 As Range, _
        rX5 As Range, rY5 As Range, rX6 As Range, rY6 As Range
    Dim rChartPos As Range
    Dim chtO As ChartObject

    Set rX1 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C" & LastRow).Select 
    Set rY1 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("F5:F80")
    Set rX2 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80")
    Set rY2 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("J5:J80")
    Set rX3 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80")
    Set rY3 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("L5:L80")
    Set rX4 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80")
    Set rY4 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("P5:P80")
    Set rX5 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80")
    Set rY5 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("T5:T80")
    Set rX6 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80")
    Set rY6 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("X5:X80")

    ' location and dimensions of the chart
    Set rChartPos = Worksheets("PLOTS").Range("O2:X28")
    With rChartPos
        Set chtO = .Parent.ChartObjects.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
        chtO.Name = "Finance Plots"
    End With

    'Plot the Whole Finance CHART
    With chtO.Chart

        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

        ' First series
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = rX1
            .Values = rY1
            .Name = "A"
        End With

        ' Second series
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = rX2
            .Values = rY2
            .Name = "B"
        End With

        ' Third series
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = rX3
            .Values = rY3
            .Name = "C"
        End With

        ' Fourth series
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = rX4
            .Values = rY4
            .Name = "D"
        End With

        ' Fifth series
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = rX5
            .Values = rY5
            .Name = "E"
        End With

        ' Sixth Series
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = rX6
            .Values = rY6
            .Name = "F"
        End With

        .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Finance Plot"

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the `.Select` code going? What's not working exactly? Is there an error being thrown?

Comment: "Run-time error '1004'
Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: On the line where i put

 Set rX1 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C" & LastRow).Select

Comment: You should update the question *with the code which is failing* - make it easier on us...

Comment: Done, its the line that reads

Set rX1 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C" & LastRow).Select

Comment: Where is `LastRow` assigned?

Comment: Also, you have a reference, `rX1`, so I would just use it and not select anything.

Comment: Ok yeah that makes sense. I dont define LastRow anywhere, do I have to write a sub routine in order to find the last row in that spreadsheet? / How would i go about implementing that in my code?

Comment: `LastRow =Worksheets("Finance").Cells(65000,3).end(xlup).row` should be enough.

Comment: Do i have to initialize LastRow as Variant or some other type?

Comment: It's not mandatory, but good practice. `Dim LastRow as Long` should be sufficient.

Comment: And as far as I can tell, you can remove the `.Select`.

Comment: YES!!!! That works amazingly. But now it messed up my graph and it only displays every other item on the X-Axis. Any ideas on how to force all of the data points to show up?

Comment: Also, can you explain to me why you chose xlup instead of xldown?

Comment: Are there blanks between each of your x points?

Comment: You could have used `xldown` but then you would need to start at the top of your data range and hope there were no blanks in the midst of that range.

Comment: There are not any black cells its all sandwhiched together from cell "5" to the last cell

Comment: How do that way? Start at cell B5 and go to the first emply cell down the rows

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: I think i figured everything out actually! Thanks for your help man. Can I like +karma you somehow?

Comment: I'll repost my comments as an answer and you can do that there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, dim and assign a value to `LastRow` as this variable is used without being assigned.

```
'Find the last row of column C
Dim LastRow as Long
LastRow = Worksheets("Finance").Cells(65000, 3).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then remove the `.Select` as it is not needed.

```
Set rX1 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C" & LastRow)
```